# Beamer Code Snippets Slide by Slide

Tags: beamer

I would like my slide presentation to display one item at a time, where the codesnippet is considered another item. Here's what I have.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Test Slide}

    \defverbatim[colored]\codesnippet{
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{blue}]
        def main():
            <statements>
    \end{lstlisting}
    }

    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> test
        \item<2-> test
        \codesnippet
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What happens with my current code is that item<1-> appears on the first slide, but then item 1 and item 2 appear on the second slide together with codesnippet. On slide 2, I just want item 1 and item 2 without the codesnippet, and then have item 1, item 2, and codesnippet appear on slide 3. If i try to nest codesnippet in another item like so, then I get an extra item after the code snippet.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> test
    \item<2-> test
    \item<3->{\codesnippet}
\end{itemize}
```

How can I treat a code snippet like an item that can be added to the next slide? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome ! You are misunderstanding the meaning of the overlay specifications you use. When using `<x-y>` means that something will be shown on `frame`s `x` to `y`. So if you want everything to appear alone, just ommit the `-`. Have a look at the `\only` and `\onslide` commands too.You could remplace your `itemize` with `\begin{itemize}item<1> test\item<2> test\end{itemize}\only<3>{\codesnippet}\end{frame}\end{document}`

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the response! I realize that my question is actually not clearly written. I didn't mean to say that I want everything appearing alone on a slide, what I meant was that items appear sequentially on top of the past items and the code snippet is like another item. For example, on slide 2, I want just item 1 and item 2, and NOT the code snippet. On slide 3, I want item 1, item 2, and the codesnippet. I will edit the original question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not know why, but the problem seems to come from the definition of `\codesnippet`. If you replace it with the explicit expression of its content, it works fine. Do you really need to define this macro ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Test Slide}


    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> test
        \item<2-> test
        \item<3-> 
        \begin{lstlisting}
def main():
    <statements>
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work. The macro was definitely not mandatory, it was a post on creating code listings so I just used that format.